# Extracting values and plot Box-plot from forecast objects

Tags: r, boxplot, r-caret, forecast

I made some forecast with forecast package with several models.Example of this models you can see below:

```
    # CODE

library(fpp2) # required for the data
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
#HOLT WINTER
fc <- hw(subset(hyndsight,end=length(hyndsight)-35),
         damped = TRUE, seasonal="multiplicative", h=35)
autoplot(hyndsight) +
  autolayer(fc, series="HW multi damped", PI=FALSE)+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Daily forecasts"))
#ETS
ets_f <- forecast(subset(hyndsight,end=length(hyndsight)-35),
        , h=35)
autoplot(hyndsight) +
  autolayer(ets_f, series="ETS", PI=FALSE)+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Daily forecasts"))
```

So next steep is comparation between models with RMSE. Namely this package can automatically plot all this results RMSE and also (Rsquared and MAE).You can see that with code below:

```
#CARET
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

MY_DATA111<-data.frame(uschange[,1:2])

trainControl1 <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3,
                             savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE)
algorithmList1 <- c('lm', 'rpart')
set.seed(7)
models1 <- caretList(Consumption ~., data=MY_DATA111, trControl=trainControl1, methodList=algorithmList1)
results1 <- resamples(models1)
summary(results1)
dotplot(results1)
```

Output of this model for RMSE with 30-resamples is as fallow:

```
Call:
summary.resamples(object = results1)

Models: lm, rpart 
Number of resamples: 30 

RMSE 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
lm    0.3624163 0.4959485 0.5582943 0.5940259 0.6851297 0.9484492    0
rpart 0.4514924 0.5046020 0.6208663 0.6332712 0.7370780 0.9759921    0
```

[image]

So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem and extract values from first two model from forecast package in order to plot box-plot like example of Caret package for RMSE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get  forecast mean with `ets_f$mean` and calculate rmse by hand.

```
# Extract forecasted values
forcasted_values <- ets_f$mean
actual_values <- subset(hyndsight,start=length(hyndsight)-36)

# Example ar model
fc2 <- ar(subset(hyndsight,end=length(hyndsight)-35))
for_values2 <- forecast(fc2, h=35)$mean

# Prepare output data.frame
result <- data.frame(
  model = c("hw",  
            "ar"),
  rmse = c(sqrt(mean((forcasted_values - actual_values)^2)), 
           sqrt(mean((for_values2 - actual_values)^2)))
)

#Box plot
boxplot(result$rmse ~ result$model)
```